# Display Vertical data into Horizontal data with Oracle preventing duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, group-by

Querying the table "`user_hours`" with fetches data in below format:

```
ID   User_ID  Name   Date       User Hours
---  ------  ----  ---------   -------
1    1       foo   1-12-2014   null
2    2       bar   1-12-2014   null
3    3       zam   2-12-2014   8
4    3       zam   3-12-2014   4
```

I'm trying to get a query so records with same `User_ID` should display like below:

```
User_ID  Name   Date       User Hours
------  -----  -----       -----
1       foo    1-12-2014   null
2       bar    1-12-2014   null
3       zam    2-12-2014   8
3       zam    3-12-2014   4
```

Here you can observer that `User_ID` `3` with name `zam` is repeated twice but with hours `8` and `4`. If I `group_by` then single entry will be shown but then `hours` display will be an issue.

How can I prevent duplicate `User_ID` display and show correct hours for relevant `Date` and `Hours`.

Comment: In the title you say "Oracle", yet you have tagged the question with `mysql` - what are you really using?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the query that you want is:

```
SELECT User_ID, Name, Date, UserHours
FROM table t
ORDER BY User_ID, Date;
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User_ID, Name, SUM(UserHours)
FROM table t
GROUP BY User_ID, Name
ORDER BY User_ID, Name;
```

If I understood you correctly, you want to show sum of hours, right?

Comment: How can we show that for `user_id=3`, `date = 2-12-2014`, hours are `8` and for `date = 3-12-2014` hours are `4` ?

Comment: Add `UserHours` in both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: Will the query be like `SELECT user_id, name, hours, SUM(hours)
FROM table supportContacts
GROUP BY user_id, name, hours
ORDER BY user_id, name;` ?

Comment: I still don’t get your requirements precisely. It seems that you want to show 3D data in 2D view. Either you have to live with doubled name, or to have hours summed.

Comment: Any alternative code here for the same ? What you are thinking is correct. Or through php loop we can display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.name, a.date_ent, SUM(a.hours) hours
FROM supportContacts a
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.name, a.date_ent
ORDER BY a.user_id, a.name, a.date_ent
```

Check [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ffb87/13)

**OUTPUT**

```
| USER_ID | NAME |  DATE_ENT | HOURS |
|---------|------|-----------|-------|
|       1 |  foo | 1-12-2014 |     0 |
|       2 |  bar | 1-12-2014 |     0 |
|       3 |  zam | 2-12-2014 |     8 |
|       3 |  zam | 3-12-2014 |     4 |
```

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Check my updated answer with fiddle demo